# Cursor between the wrong characters when clicking an inactive NSTextField with the "Truncate Head" Line Break

Tags: xcode, macos, nstextfield

I used Interface Builder to create an NSTextField and set its Line Break to Truncate Head (because if its text is too long to display all at once, I'd rather see the last few words than the first few).

My problem is that the modified Line Break compromises my ability to place my cursor in a specific position when making the NSTextField active (a.k.a. First Responder) by clicking the mouse. In this example, the NSTextField is not active, and I attempt to place my cursor between the "L" and "A" in "lazy".

[image: before click]

After clicking, the cursor appears before the word "over".

[image: after click]

Clearly, the NSTextField is ignoring the modified Line Break, and positioning the cursor as if it were the default. Can I achieve the effect of Truncate Head but keep the ability to place the cursor in a specific location by clicking?

I had the idea to record the `mouseDown` location, compare that to `attributedStringValue`'s size, and calculate where the cursor should go, but I quickly got in over my head.

> *Original question:  NSTextField keep scrolling at the end*
>
> I have the following silly problem:
>
> I placed a single-line NSTextField on my View. The idea would be that it contains a long URL, but in my case mostly the ending is interesting.
>
> So I would like the content to appear like scrolled to the end (so the beginning is not visible if it is longer than the textfield). The problem is that I do not know how to set this properly. I tried the "Text Direction" option to Right To Left which then displays properly, but as soon the user clicks on the field it jumps back to the beginning, thus confusing the user.
>
> Please let me know what I am missing.
>
> Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for rephrasing my question, now I hope someone knows the answer :)